# Enable "swipe" to activate a side menu

Tags: java, android, eclipse, menu, swipe

I recently create an application that implement a side menù.
The menù actually appear by tapping on the left-up corner but i would like to implement a swipe action (like facebook app) to call it.

Here is part of the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Eula.show(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    icon = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
    sideNavigationView = (SideNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.side_navigation_view);
    sideNavigationView.setMenuItems(R.menu.side_navigation_menu);
    sideNavigationView.setMenuClickCallback(this);

    if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_TITLE)) {
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE);
        int resId = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_RESOURCE_ID, 0);
        setTitle(title);
        icon.setImageResource(resId);
    }

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        sideNavigationView.toggleMenu();
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSideNavigationItemClick(int itemId) {
    switch (itemId) {
    case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item1:
        Intent moppen = new Intent(this, page1.class);     
        startActivity(moppen);
        break;
    case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item2:
        Intent page2 = new Intent(this, page2.class);     
        startActivity(page2);
        break;
    case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item3:
        Intent plaatjes = new Intent(this, page3.class);     
        startActivity(plaatjes);
        break;
    case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item4:
        Intent special = new Intent(this, page4.class);     
        startActivity(special);
        break;
    case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item5:
        Intent over = new Intent(this, page5.class);     
        startActivity(over);
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Which lib are you using??

Comment: actionlibrary + slidelibrary

Comment: use sliding menu lib it is very easy to implement it, and it has the fuctionality you want to perform...

Answer (score 0):

Use this lib https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu , then write this in oncreate()

```
 SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
 menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
```

then in the menu.

```
menu.toggle();
```